# direct ethernet connect from Windows to Linux machine

Tags: networking, ssh, ethernet, raspberry-pi

I have a windows 7 laptop, and a raspberry pi running linux(raspbian). I have configured a wifi dongle on raspberry pi, and it's connecting to a wifi network. But now I want to connect my Windows machine to raspberry pi through a direct ethernet cable using ssh without going through wifi network. I have tried several ways, but none of them worked.

I tried to set a static ip address for my raspberry pi, and then configure windows machine within the same subnetwork. It worked well, but my raspberry pi cannot connect to wifi network . The wifi network is using dhcp, and I guess there is a conflict.

Basically, I am looking for a solution to make the raspberry pi working good with the wifi network, and at the same time my windows machine can ssh to it using a direct ethernet cable. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: set static ip for both. . can u ping to each other now?

Comment: are the ethernet ip addresses on the same subnet as the wifi connections? IIRC they shouldn't be.

Comment: The ethernet ip addresses is the same subnet as wifi. let me change it and see what happens

Comment: i cannot ping each other.

Comment: you need to set routing tables o both pcs, and enable IPv4 forwarding on windows machine